# How can I write this with the correct set notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have had trouble expressing set notation for part of some code that I have been working on. So I have a universal set, $U$ for example, that contains $n$ number of elements. From this universal set I have to form subsets that contain at least two elements but not more than $n$. So, subset $A_1$, (where the subscript represents the number of elements) is not valid. Also, once $A_2$ is defined, the next subset of U that is $A_3$ is the super set of $A_2$,and so on. How can I write this in a few sentences so that I don't have to explain each and every subset. The total elements I have are 49 so I assume that I will have 47 subsets given that $A_1$ does meat the least number of elements criteria and $A_{49}$ is already the universal. Thanks for your Help !

I just want to point out that the ordering does not matter, because I know that there could be many combinations of $A_2$, so once $A_2$ is randomly chosen the next element does not need to be in a particular order.

Comment: You might call it a *chain* of subsets of $U$. Denoted $A_2 \subset A_3 \subset \cdots \subset A_n$

Comment: It's definitely a chain, but with $|A_k|=k$ for $k=2,\dots,n.$ This could be defined as a maximal chain of the poset: $$\{S\subseteq U\mid 2\leq |S|\leq n\},$$ at least if $|U|\geq n.$